# React.useRef([]) : Error React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to ref an element by an array in React. it throws me an error,

```
function ProposalBuilder() {
  const [hovered, setHovered] = useState(false);
  const [length, setLength] = useState(1);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);
  const toggleHover = () => setHovered(!hovered);
  setLength(1);
  const containerRef = React.useRef([]);
  const hoverContentRef = [];
  const hoverOutlineRef = [];
  const OutlineElement = (props) => {
    //console.log(containerRef[props.index].current.getBoundingClientRect());
  return (
    <>
    <div class="builder-tool builder-outline-content-hover">block</div>
    <div class="builder-tool builder-hover-outline"  ></div>
    </>
  );
};
  return (
    <div className="pro__mangement">
      <div className="pro__mangemnt__header">
        <h6>Proposal Management Add / Edit</h6>
      </div>
      <div className="essantials__row">
        <div className="essantial__head">
          <p>ESSANTIALS</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      


        {/* Box section */}
        <div class="content">
        <div className="wrapper_builder">
              <div class="page_layout">
              <div builder-element="BlockElement" builder-container builder-wrapper  ref={ref=>containerRef.current.push(ref)}  className={hovered ? '"container container_blank builder-class-element-highlighted' : '"container container_blank'} onMouseEnter={toggleHover}
      onMouseLeave={toggleHover}>
                
              </div>
              {hovered && <OutlineElement index={containerRef.length - 1}/>}
              
              </div>
        </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     
     <div className='essantial__button__row'>
            
             <Button onClick={''} id='essantial__button'>Add </Button>
             <Button onClick={''} id='essantial__button'> Pdf / Excel </Button>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am adding many BlockElement later
Currently I have one
I want to refer the element by index
I get an error

Comment: remove   `setLength(1);`

Comment: Can you clarify what is meant by "ref an element by an array in React"? I don't see where any refs are attached to any elements.

Comment: I did not got it intially.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State length  from `const [length, setLength] = useState(1);` renders infinitely due to setLength(1); later in the code. its already having the default value 1 from the init condition. Also if you need to run setLength after may be try use useEffect with empty argument ,

```
useEffect(()=>{
setLength(1)
},[])
```

So it runs only once.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have this line?

```
setLength(1);
```

This will update state, which reruns the component which runs this line, which updates state... In other words, an infinite loop.

Comment: It will bail on rendering, not on parsing the component. You stil lget an infinite loop because react needs to recalculate the state to make sure nothing changed. Here's an example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-night-dpxde?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

To hava an array of ref you could:

1. use one ref with an array of current elements:

   ```
   const containerRef = useRef([]);
   ...
   <input ref={el => containerRef.current[id] = el} />
   ```
2. use an Array of ref:

   ```
   const containerRef = list.map(x => useRef(null));
   ...
   <input ref={containerRef[id]} />
   ```

Note that the second option is not a good practice because we are calling an Hook inside a loop.

Comment: The second example is incorrect, you would need to create a ref, i.e. `const inputRef = list.map(x => createRef(null));`.

Comment: @DrewReese with `useRef` I'm creating a ref. Right?

Comment: Yes, but you can't call React hooks in loops. `createRef` also creates React refs.

Comment: @DrewReese and infact I wrote `Note that the second option is not a good practice because we are calling an Hook inside a loop.`

Comment: It's not that it is not a good practice, it is that it's completely invalid. See [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). Though it is a good practice to not write invalid code. :)

Comment: @DrewReese React docs says `Don’t call Hooks inside loops, conditions, or nested functions. Instead, always use Hooks at the top level of your React function. By following this rule, you ensure that Hooks are called in the same order each time a component renders.`. So is not totally invalid. I could proof that also the second option it works.

Comment: Are you serious? `array.map` is a loop and the `useRef` is in the nested mapping callback in your example. I don't know how the docs could be any clearer about it.

Comment: @DrewReese Ok lets say that the second option is STRONGLY discouraged. Stills the fact that is not invalid.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235090/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-giovanni-esposito).